# mass write dns records through import-csv

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have created a script to try to fetch values from a csv file that basically contains these commas: Name, Data

Name is hostname and Data is the ipv4Address of each hostname.

So the csv is presented simply like this:

Name,Data
DC01, 10.0.0.1
another-host.domain.com, 10.0.0.2
etc...

I tried running something like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\records\\powershelltest\fqdns.domain.com.csv"
$Name = "Name"
$Data = "Data"
foreach ($LINE in $csv)
{Add-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $Name -RecordData $Data} -WhatIf -Passthru
```

The script is prompting for values, but the idea is to write those values as a DNSServerResourceRecord without prompting to manually type them. (the primary zones are already there)

I also tried sometthing like:

```
$Data = import-csv C:\filepath
foreach ($record in $data){​add-dnsserverresourcerecord -name $($Name) -Ip $($data)
```

Can anybody enlighten me?

None of the solutions are working.

Answer (score 1):

Your not actually using the values from the csv, your just using the strings `Name` and `Data`. This code hopefully demonstrates:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\\records\\powershelltest\\fqdns.domain.com.csv"
$Name = "Name"
$Data = "Data"
foreach($line in $csv){
    
    write-Host $line.Name
    write-Host $line.Data
    write-Host $Name
    write-Host $Data

    # ie
    # Add-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $line.Name -RecordData $line.Data -WhatIf -Passthru
    # NOT
    # Add-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $Name -RecordData $Data -WhatIf -Passthru
}
```

(I assume the `-whatif` used with `Add-DnsServerResourceRecord` is intentional)

Comment: thnx for the input. not quite sure if i understood. 
the -whatif is indeed intentional. but the idea is to update the dnsresourcerecord in bulk, by importing the values from the $csv not just printing the values on the terminal.

Comment: @illysound Read this answer again.. This demonstrates in your code you are iterating the records from the csv using variable `$line` (or `$record` in the second part of your question), but **ignore** that completely in the loop. This variable holds data from the csv in every iteration, so you need to use its **properties** `$line.Name` and `$line.Data`

Comment: Your taking my answer too literally - see additional code comments. This is not a code writing service ;-) Look at my code and compare it to yours, then you can adapt it to your situation. Good luck! (FYI Add `Write-Host $Name` inside your foreach loop in your existing code - you should see the problem)